# Load specific image, then load the entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, lazy-loading

I have a background image and lots of product image. Shortly, %88 of entire page is image. But when i refresh the page. Some products are displaying. After that my background is coming. Then other divs, images are coming.

What i want to do is my background images comes first. Then others are must be displayed. Sync or async it is not important.

**What i tried:** 
i replaced my background image div to the top of the dom. Not worked.

```
window.onload=function () {
document.getElementById("theBackgroundImage").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Not worked also.

I tried several things before. But i have still same issue.

Comment: are you using a library for lazy loading? if so can you exclude your bg image from lazy loading?

Comment: What you are doing is simply changing visibility of the image. It is still loaded by the browser. You need to lazy load your images after the images have been loaded. Also do you think you really need having an image that's 88% (based on size ?) of your page ?

Comment: No, i am not using lazy loading right now. But i thought using lazy load earlier.

Comment: @LaurentB %88 of my entire page is image. Just this page, there is no text, empty areas. Just images are displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you will need to detect when **all** your images are loaded. Or preferably when all the images you want displayed first.

Then i see two options here. For both, i'm going to use a library that helps in detecting when images have been loaded : https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

**1st option**

Just display your image.

```js
imagesLoaded( 'img', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".displayAfter").forEach(e => e.style.visibility = 'visible'
  )
});
```

```css
.displayAfter {
  visibility : hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

Image here :
<img width="50px" height="50px" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50?random" />
Lazy loaded image here :
<img class="displayAfter" width="50px" height="50px" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" />
```

**2nd option**

Do not load your image first (for instance src empty or pointing to blank image) then change the src attribute of your image. Here i use a `data-src` attribute in the image that i simply insert into the image `src` attribute once all the other images are loaded.

```js
imagesLoaded( 'img', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".displayAfter").forEach(e => 
    e.setAttribute('src', e.getAttribute('data-src'))
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>

Image here :
<img width="50px" height="50px" src="https://picsum.photos/50/50?random" />
Lazy loaded image here :
<img class="displayAfter" data-src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" width="50px" height="50px" />
```

Comment: i am creating all images dynamicaly. just added data-src and some id for pass javascript and its done. I like that. Thanks. I used 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the following to top in your css file

```
  #theBackgroundImage{
  background : url(..)
  }
```

and maybe you need to use (Lazy Loading Images) => [url](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/)

Comment: Funny. I'm using the same method with 'data-src'. BTW, this will only load image when they are visible using a listener on the scroll event. Probably not what OP wants.